# Why keyup/keydown are not fired on 'select'?

Tags: javascript, keyboard-events

Why no keyboard event is fired when the client moves between `select` options? Is there any other event sent?

How to reproduce:

- Focus on the select element.
- Open the select options.
- Move through the select options using the keyboard (up/down) arrows.

Result: 
 While you are moving through the options using the up/down keyboard keys no event is sent.

HTML

```
<!-- The second value will be selected initially -->
<select name="text"> <!--Supplement an id here instead of using 'text'-->
  <option value="value1">Value 1</option> 
  <option value="value2" selected>Value 2</option>
  <option value="value3">Value 3</option>
</select>
```

JS

```
function onkeyEvent(evt ){
    console.log(evt);
}
            window.addEventListener('keyup', onkeyEvent, true);
            window.addEventListener('keydown', onkeyEvent, true);
            window.addEventListener('keypress', onkeyEvent, true);
```

Change event is fired only after an option is selected, not while the client is selecting(moving through the options) so I'm not accepted it as an answer.

Comment: `select`s use a `'change'` Event.

Comment: you can use `change`

Comment: `change` is fired when an option is already selected not while the client is browsing the options.

Comment: As OP says, the `change` event is only fired when a new selection is made, whereas they want to capture the event when toggling between the `option` values using the keyboard _before_ a new selection is chosen.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it using a setTimeOut like this:

```
$("selector").on('keydown', (ev)=> { 
    if (ev.key == "Enter") {
        setTimeout(() => {
            $("selector_to_focus").focus();            
        }, 100);
    } 
});
```

In my case, time execution cause that jump twice to inputs after pressed enter key.

Answer (score -2):

As others have mentioned, to obtain the key events from a `<select>` element, you can add an event listener to the element's [`change`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change) event.